# Use AWS SDK without credentials to confirm a SNS subscription --> No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sns, aws-sdk-net

I don't have an AWS account. I do have an HTTP POST webhook that should receive to the HTTPS endpoint of a SNS topic. When trying to confirm the subscription there is the following error message in the logs:

> No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured

I used the official AWS SDK for .NET calling the [ConfirmSubscriptionAsync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/index.html?page=SNS/MSNSConfirmSubscriptionConfirmSubscriptionRequest.html) method. The purpose of me using the SDK was that it itself should handle the signature validation, as is proposed in the AWS docs. However, this cannot be done if I don't provide myself have an AWS account. Is this expected?

Here's the code that should handle the incoming requests

```cs
    public class Func
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(Func))]
        public async Task Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "/receive/sns")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            if (req.Headers.TryGetValue("x-amz-sns-message-type" , out var msgType))
            {
                if (msgType == "SubscriptionConfirmation")
                {
                    var snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient();
                    var subscriptionRequest = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<ConfirmSubscriptionRequest>(req.Body);
                    var subscriptionResponse = await snsClient.ConfirmSubscriptionAsync(subscriptionRequest);
                    log.LogTrace(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(subscriptionResponse));
                }
                else if (msgType == "Notification")
                {
                    var notification = await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<AwsSnsNotification>(req.Body);
                    log.LogTrace(JsonSerializer.Serialize(notification));
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("`x-amz-sns-message-type header`", msgType, "Allowed as per AWS doc: `SubscriptionConfirmation`, `Notification`");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("x-amz-sns-message-type header not set");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved it without needing to create an instance of the client. The message model exposes a the static `ParseMessage` method. Then on the instance of Message I can invoke the `IsMessageSignatureValid` method. Subsequently I just HTTP GET the subscription confirmation url and done. Posting here so hopefully this is helpful for others as well.

```cs
    public class Func
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(Func))]
        public async Task Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "receive/sns")] HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
        {
            if (req.Headers.TryGetValue("x-amz-sns-message-type" , out var msgType))
            {
                var reqBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEndAsync();
                var msg = Message.ParseMessage(reqBody);
                if (!msg.IsMessageSignatureValid())
                {
                    throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("Message signature invalid");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (msgType == "SubscriptionConfirmation")
                    {
                        await Http.GetAsync(msg.SubscribeURL);
                    }
                    else if (msgType == "Notification")
                    {
                        log.LogTrace(msg.MessageText);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("`x-amz-sns-message-type header`", msgType, "Allowed as per AWS doc: `SubscriptionConfirmation`, `Notification`");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("x-amz-sns-message-type header not set");
            }
        }
    }
```