# Use spring-cloud-aws-message without credentials to confirm a SNS subscription

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns, spring-cloud-aws

I'm using `spring-cloud-aws-messaging` to be able to easily confirm `SNS` topic subscription and receive notification through an HTTPS endpoint in my service.

```java
@NotificationSubscriptionMapping
public void confirmSubscription(final NotificationStatus status) {}
```

For that specific process, `aws` credentials shouldn't be necessary, the flow is validated through a certificate validation between SNS request to my service and a call to the provided URL matching the certificate's signature, but still when SNS tries to confirm the subscription I get:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
```

Is there a way to go around it?

Here we can find an example of someone that could do it using the .NET `aws-sdk` directly:

[Use AWS SDK without credentials to confirm a SNS subscription --> No RegionEndpoint or ServiceURL configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66744973/use-aws-sdk-without-credentials-to-confirm-a-sns-subscription-no-regionendpo)

So it's probably possible to do it in java with the SDK directly but I still wonder if with `spring-cloud-aws` it's possible.

I appreciate a lot any help,
Cheers!

Comment: A bit of a hack, but you can set dummy values for the creds. Won't matter if it doesn't actually call the aws api.

Comment: Hey @jordanm,  yea I tried to use dummy creds but now I'm getting
```com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AmazonSNSException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: InvalidClientTokenId```. It seems I really need valid credentials. I wonder if I can create an IAM user with no permissions at all and generate the credentials from it, I'm gonna give it a try

Comment: It will need permission for something because it does appear to be sending a request. If you setup the IAM user without a policy and still get an access denied, you will just need to create a policy with the relevant SNS permission.

Comment: Yea, good point, I'll definitely need some SNS permissions, that's the direction I'll be going for.  It's pretty frustrating that there's no way for the lib to use `subscribeUrl` directly and avoid asking for the credentials